# Apply date filter on Sublist with additional conditions c# Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model and properties are like below

```
Subscription
------------
 Number 
 Id
 SubscriptionLines
    [ProductNo
    StartDate]
```

---

I am trying to find a Subscription with a match on ProductNo now and using this linq

```
List<Subscription> _subscriptions = (from i in _subscriptions
                                     where i.SubscriptionLines.Any(l => l.ProductNo == isbn) 
                                     select i).ToList();
```

I have to apply a condition on `StartDate` ie to fetch the subscriptions with recent value for StartDate & match on ProductNo

```
s123
1
[
    {
    9876
    31-2-2019
    }
    {
    456
    31-1-2020
    }
]

s456
2
[
    {
    9876
    12-2-2020
    }
    {
    456
    31-1-2020
    }
]

s756
2
[
    {
    986
    12-2-2020
    }
    {
    456
    31-1-2020
    }
]
```

From this sample set of data we have 2 matches for product No 9876, but we need to fetch the one with most recent date and in this case it is s456 with value 12-2-2020

What adjustment can be done on the query to add the date parameter?

Comment: LINQ to Objects is essentially iterations over IEnumerables. It's not going to run *faster* than iterating the enumerables. Nothing prevents you from transforming the objects or selecting specific items, or having multiple `where` clauses. I suspect you can solve your problem with [MoreLINQ's MaxBy](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs). You can flatten the hierarchy with `from s in subscriptions from l in s.SubscriptionLines`, or `SelectMany`, use `MaxBy` to find the subscription with the max date and return it

Answer (score 0):

If your intension is to get ProductNo and StartDate by isbn and max StartDate, try this.

I'm not sure whether it is a good solution.

```
var _subscriptions = (from i in subscriptions
                      where i.SubscriptionLines.Any(l => l.ProductNo == isbn)
                      select i)
                        .SelectMany(m => m.SubscriptionLines)
                        .GroupBy(o => o.StartDate)
                        .Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(grpElm => grpElm.StartDate)).First().ToList();
```